# Insert same code around different filenames

Tags: sublimetext2

I am making a small online database that is accessible through the form of checkboxes for download. I was wondering if there was some way to list all of the filenames available for download in Sublime Text 2 and insert the same code around each filename?

Everything is functional, it would just save me a lot of repetitive copy and pasting if there is a faster way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use search/replace on a text editor with regular expressions.

`^` and `$` represent the beginning and end of a line - thus allowing you to easily surround each line with the appropriate text.

Answer (score 2):

Use SublimeText Find & Replace. Click the Regex button (it looks like a `*` to the left of the search box)

In the Find box, insert: `(^.*$)`

In the replace box: `[yourcode]$1[yourcode]`

Where `[yourcode]` is what you want to insert into the box.

So, if you want to make them all `<li>` then your replace box would be: 
`<li>$1</li>`

Remember to use escape `\` characters where they are needed, in case you need to insert restricted characters.

`^` - beginning of a new line.

`.` - wildcard

`*` - any number of the previous character in the sequence (in this case a wildcard, so any text)

`$` - the end of a line

`()` - denotes a block, it's how the `$1` knows what text to put in it's place.

[Sublime Text Search and Replace](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_overview.html)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can copy the newline character (as in copy the end of one line to the beginning of the next line), and replace that with whatever text you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the regular expression search / replace feature in Notepad++.